# Jquery isn't working in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Okay, so I'm trying to make a list of links and depending on which link you select it will display a different div container. I want it so only one div shows at a time. I have the code and it is working as I'd like, however, when I load it in IE it won't work. I've heard that logs play a part in this. How do I make this code IE compatible and or if you have another solution that would work I'm opened to hearing it as well.

My code:

```
    <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!--Footer and Navigation Div's-->
    <div id="bg"><img src="images/bg.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p><span>Menu</span></p>
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul><a href="#">Link 1</a></ul>
                    <ul><a href="#">Link 2</a></ul>
                    <ul><a href="#">Link 3</a></ul>
                    <ul><a href="#">Link 4</a></ul>
                </div>
        </div>

    <!--END Footer and Navigation Div's-->

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="a">
            <p>this is a</p>
        </div>   
        <div class="b">
            <p>this is b</p>
        </div>
        <div class="c">
            <p>this is c</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d">
            <p>this is d</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.parent  div').hide();

    $('#nav a').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).index('a'));
        var $div = $('.parent > div').eq($(this).index('#nav a'));
        $div.show();
        $('.parent > div').not($div).hide();
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you observe when it doesn't work in the way you're expecting?

Comment: You should also mention the IE version

Comment: You should also use a more updated version of jquery, 1.4.2 is quite old

Comment: When I open it up in IE 7, It displays all of the divs already. The links don't change when the links are clicked or anything in Chrome and Firefox, the page loads with the links and when you click a link it displays the corresponding div container, only opening one at a time.

Comment: Try removing console.log - console isn't an object in IE7

Answer (score -1):

This is the very first thing you should learn about jQuery . Always use $(document).ready... Example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.parent  div').hide();

        $('#nav a').click(function() {
            console.log($(this).index('a'));
            var $div = $('.parent > div').eq($(this).index('#nav a'));
            $div.show();
            $('.parent > div').not($div).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Since their javascript is at the end of the document, `$(document).ready` does not matter here

Comment: it could be a comment

Comment: Please elaborate why it shouldn't matter? The DOM is loaded when this script starts running, but the entire page is still loading.

Comment: Not neccesary to use dom ready when the jQuery is at the bottom of the page (because the page has loaded by the time it does). There's nothing to suggest that this solves the problem in IE7.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
$('#nav a').live('click',function() {
```

or

```
$('#nav a').bind('click',function() {
```

Comment: Where would I put that exactly? This is my first time ever using Jquery.

Comment: $('#nav a').live('click',function() {

Comment: `.live` is obsolete, it's going to be deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: You should expand your answer and explain _why_ so the asker actually gains knowledge instead of learning to just copy-paste a few things until it works.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!